# Differential equations, convergence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I am dealing with the following  matrix.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0&a  & a & a & c & c &c  & c\\ 
 a&  0& a &a  &  c&  c&  c& c\\ 
 a& a &0 &a  &  c& c & c & c\\ 
 a&  a& a &0  & c &c  &c  &c \\ 
 c& c & c & c &  0&  b& b &b \\ 
 c& c & c &  c&  b&0  & b & b\\ 
 c& c & c & c & b & b &0 & b\\ 
 c& c & c & c &  b&  b& b &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

We have $a > b >1/2$ and $c<1/2$, and $ a, b, c \ge 0$ and  $ a, b, c \le 1$.
The typical
replicator dynamics equation is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d t} = [ Ax - (x, Ax)] x = (Ax) x - (x, Ax) x, \label{A1}
\end{equation}

where  $\frac{d x}{d t}$ denotes derivative with respect to the time variable $t$, $(x, Ax)$ denotes the usual inner product, i.e. the dot product, of the vectors $x$ and $Ax$, and $(Ax) x$ is the vector whose $i$-th component is the product of the $i$-th components of $(Ax)$ and $x$
(i.e. the ``pointwise product" of two vectors).
The matrix $A$ is called the payoff matrix or fitness matrix.

Is it possible show that the dynamics converge to $x_1^*=(1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 0, 0, 0,0)$ or $x_2^*=(0, 0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4,1/4)$. I am not sure what are the stable points of the equation. We suppose we are working in simplex, which means sum of the components of x are equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

A start:

characteristic polynomial is
$$ \left( \lambda^2 -3(a+b) \lambda + 9ab-16c^2 \right) (\lambda + a)^3 (\lambda + b)^3 $$

Two of the eigenvalues are
$$  \frac{3(a+b)\pm \sqrt {9(a-b)^2 + 64 c^2}}{2} $$
With your inequalities, the largest eigenvalue is larger than $3/2.$

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot Will Jagy! If we use Rayleigh quotient theorem, then we can bound the max, however, in Rayleigh quotient, x should not be necessary in the simplex.